# Django IndentationError in a working function

Tags: python, django

I'm so sick of Django. I wrote a Python Function which is working correct.
For reasons of visualizations I decided to make a web-page to demonstrate my function.

I added some code to my function:

```
txt_len = 0          (line 1)
if text:
    txt_len=len(text)

return txt_len
```

*it's only a example. 
But for a reason I get an IndentationError ,unexpected indent at line 1

Why? can't get it.

Comment: If this is inside a function can you post the whole function?  As is, there is no indentation error.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Django. It is a Python problem.

Comment: Telling how much you are sick will not help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see the whole function? Line 1 is just for example right? Line 1 would at the very least have to be a function definition for that return line to work.

Did you just paste a function into a django view?

**The culprit for mystery indentation errors is almost always mixing spaces and tabs.** Do you have invisible characters visible in your editor? Can you run a command to replace tabs with spaces?

Comment: line 1 is only for the example. The whole Function is a little bit to large to post it. And yes I copied the Python Function into the view.py Clearly: I have 1 Function which use the function I copied.

Comment: Yeah some Ghostwriter add some spaces to my code. Now it works. Thank You ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Running the code you present (and removing the "(line 1)" from the first line, which would yield a syntax error) gave  "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function".  I added a `def fn():` statement just above the `txt_len = 0` statement.  As I expected, that gave an "IndentationError: expected an indented block" .  To get this code to work, you need to indent everything in the function, something like:

```
def fn():
    txt_len = 0
    if text:
        txt_len=len(text)
    return txt_len
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, please provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Common problems with Python indenting include mixing tabs and spaces. The code example you posted looks okay, but it has been filtered through a formatter already. I'd recommend making sure you use only spaces for indenting.